# Class enumeration cannot be used in method logic - not sure what the issue is, or how to figure it out

Tags: java, enums, logic

As part of an assignment for school, I'm making checkers. I was trying to figure out the best way to set the type of piece (normal/king+color), and enums seemed to be the proper tool for such a thing, but I can't figure out how to use them effectively, and the reading I'm doing on enums isn't helping me to solve the issue I have with my code. In the class Checker I have this so far:

```
enum Type {RED_NORM, RED_KING, BLACK_NORM, BLACK_KING}

public Class Checker {

    int posRow;
    int posCol;
    Type checkerType;

    public Checker(...)
    {...}

    public int[] posCheck()
    {...}

    public boolean kingCheck()
    {
        boolean isKing = false;
        if(checkerType == RED_NORM)
        {
            if (posRow == 10)
                checkerType = RED_KING;
        }
        else if(checkerType = BLACK_NORM)
            if (posCol == 0)
                checkerType = BLACK_KING;

    return isKing;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, obviously, but I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong (and I can't figure out what exactly it is that I need to google). RED_NORM, RED_KING, etc. all say they cannot be resolved to a variable. I'm not sure why this doesn't work, considering the constructor is able to refer to the checkerType variable just fine (I think)? the only errors Eclipse is displaying is with the RED_NORM, RED_KING, etc in the kingCheck method.

I'm having a hard time understanding the things I'm reading when I'm trying to google this (and, as i said, a hard time syntaxing my search properly). Any help would be appreciated - apologies in advance for what seems to be a moronic question.

Comment: Using `=` instead of `==` in an if statement almost never does the right thing...

Comment: @Sweeper that was just a typo when transcribing to SOF, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of directly referencing `RED_NORM, RED_KING, BLACK_NORM, BLACK_KING`, reference it like this :

`Type.RED_NORM, Type.RED_KING etc..`

When you reference it directly, the system thinks that you are referring to a variable instead of a value. You have to specify the type of value that you are using.

P.S. Whatever you want to look up, start with the simplest words, just google Java enums and you should find what you are looking for with a little bit of research. For more help, you can visit [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enum-in-java/) URL.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much!

I had look up just the words 'java enums' and whatnot, but I missed that reference nuance while I was reading, and I was getting frustrated enough that I wasn't really reading in detail.